# How to pass a variable to the minimum size key in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, dimensions

I want to pass a variable to the `minimum size` key of a node, but it doesn't work. Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{1.2 + 0.2}
  \node[draw,circle,minimum size=\R] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Clearly I could use an explicit number e.g. `minimum size= 1.4 cm` but that's not what I want. So what would be the correct way to pass a variable to `minimum size` as above?

Comment: Use `\R cm` or multiply the macro result with a unit `\R*1cm` etc. Not every key is converted to canvas unit vectors. Minimum size is independent from the canvas coordinates

Comment: @percusse Thanks this works. Is there any way to make tikz interpret everything in terms of canvas unit vectors?

Comment: No. The math engine uses point system. But TikZ prefers centimeters. That's why it feels inconsistent but it is actually not

Comment: @percusse I don't really see why this is not inconsistent. Is there any reason why it would be a bad idea to open a feature request for this on https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests?

Comment: Because TeX arithmetic works on point system. You can open a feature request of course but I don't see the benefit. You just need to give a unit and you are done.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You must specify the dimensions:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{1.2cm + 0.2cm}
```

Otherwise it is interpreted as points and the size of the circle is of the `inner sep`.

Edit:

`\node` is a command of Tikz and the default is in `cm`, as per the manual:

> If you do not provide a unit, as in (2,1), you specify a point in pgf’s xy-coordinate system. By default, the unit x-vector goes 1cm to the right and the unit y-vector goes 1cm upward.

`\pgfmathsetmacro` is a `pgfmath` command and the default is in `pt`, as per the manual:

> The mathematical engine of pgf is implicitly used whenever you specify a number or dimension in a higher-level macro.
>   [...]
>   As was explained earlier, the parser commands like \pgfmathparse will always return a result without units in it and all dimensions that have a unit like 10pt or 1in will first be converted to TEX points (pt) and, then, the unit is dropped.

Comment: If you do something like `\draw (0,0) circle (2)` the numbers are not interpreted as a point (instead of a multiple of a unit length). However as you write, if I don't give explicit dimensions in my example the number is interpreted as points. This seems to be inconsistent. Is there also a global option such that everything in a tikz picture is interpreted as a multiple of a unit vector as my first example?

Comment: @Julia What is a unit vector (in TikZ world) ? The xy coordinate system of TikZ uses _two_ vectors : x and y.

Comment: @Julia Here we are using two things. One is Tikz and the other is `pgfmath`. If no units are given, Tikz sets them as cm by default. This is natural since Tikz is at user level and cm is a "human" dimension. To the contrary, `pgfmath`uses points as the default length and converts all dimensions first to points. This is logical since it is working at a lower level where cm have no meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Not actually sure how useful/advisable this is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\newdimen\tmpvec
\tikzset{Minimum Size/.code={%
    \pgfpointxy{#1}{#1}%
    \tikzset{minimum width/.expanded=\the\csname pgf@x\endcsname,
      minimum height/.expanded=\the\csname pgf@y\endcsname}%
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, thick, dashed,
    anchor=south west, outer sep=0}]
  \draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
  \node [red, Minimum Size=1] {A};
  \node [green, y=(90:2cm), Minimum Size=1] at (2,0) {B};
  \node [blue, x=(0:2cm), y=(90:3cm), Minimum Size=1] at (0,0) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]